# Generate SQL scripts for triggers

Tags: sql, triggers, db2, generator

I often have to create trigger which will copy all contents of the rows on insert/update to another table. As some tables have 200 columns this often is a long writing of

```
CREATE TRIGGER scheme.trigger AFTER UPDATE ON scheme.table
  REFERENCING OLD as o_row NEW as n_row
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO archive (...) VALUES(...);
END;
```

This is a lot of typing. Is there an easy generator to build these type of triggers, inserts, updates?

Comment: I haven't done DB2 in years, but isn't there a data dictionary table you can reference to get the column names? Write a stored proc to output the above, while inserting into that output the list of columns? I have done that in Oracle and SQL Server, so I assume that is how you would do it in DB2.

Comment: I am planning to do an assistant tool for that but I am a bit short on time currently and was wondering if there is no freeware tool available doing this.

Comment: start with "select * from systables" and go from there. I suspect it is far easier to roll your own than to search for the exact tool. this is not that difficult a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the process has a set of input parameters and the process with these parameters is the same, you can call a stored procedure from the trigger, passing the parameters.
In this way, you do not have to recopy/recreate all these DML sentences.

Comment: This sounds quite good but the count of parameters differs from table to table. Are variable parameter lengths supported by iSeries DB2 stored procedures (maybe you know)?

Comment: Accepted as there is no tool and this is the most flexible way to handle it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a tool that generates the CREATE TRIGGER statements for you, but I've generated that DDL from a query many times, and the only view I ever needed to references was SYSCAT.COLUMNS

The following factors will simplify the trigger DDL generator query you'll be writing:
- Column names between original table and archive table are identical.
- None of the columns in the target table are defined as GENERATED ALWAYS, otherwise you'll need to omit them from your INSERT statement.